# etc. etc. usage

Tags: grammar, writing, redundancy, etc

Is there any rule to use *etc.* twice like **etc. etc.**

Comment: It is something that seems to run with certain authors.  One who comes to mind is George Orwell.  He peppers his non-fiction with "etc etc", "etc etc etc", "and so on and so on", and his favourite "and so on and so forth".

Comment: I believe that this is a matter of style, and that that’s what the voters who said “This question is opinion-based.” meant.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(rhetorical_device) "Repetition (rhetorical device) (at Wikipedia)"), [this](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/repetition-examples-in-writing.html "Repetition Examples in Literature and Writing"), [this](https://literaryterms.net/repetition/ "Repetition: Definition and Examples") and [this](https://thejohnfox.com/repetition-examples/ "17 Fantastic Repetition Examples in Literature"). … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  This question might be acceptable at [Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) and/or [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), but I don’t know — I’m not a member of either of those stacks.  Check their rules (and their Tours) before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Two or even three "et cetera"s in a row are idiomatic and reasonably common, but informal. Multiple "et cetera"s can be used to emphasize the great number of omitted items or the speaker's feelings about them. A more familiar example of duplicating words for emphasis is "it was really, really good", which means the same thing as "it was really good", but expresses greater intensity.